# AR(2) considering just the second lag

Tags: r, time-series, augmented-reality, arima

I have this code for an ARIMA(1,1,0)

```
arima(Windows(diff(log.variable,1),
              start=1985, perder=c(1,0,0),
              include.means=FALSE, transform.pars=FALSE))
```

How can I define an AR(2) that considera only the second lag, not the first and the second lag?

Answer (score 0):

the diff function has a build in lag indicator the default is 1 but you can specify

```
x = 1:10

diff(x) #lag = 1

diff(x,2)
diff(x, lag=2) #same as above
```

on your code just change diff(log.variable,1) to diff(log.variable,2) and you will get the lag 2 diff

But a better question is why are you trying random lag numbers there are way to calculate the proper number of lags in a model.